# how to make parent height relevant to children but also don't increase parent height when children height increases

Tags: html, css, height

As the title describes i have a parent div which contains children divs.

I can't know how many children there will be so i can't give a fixed height to the parent.

The height of the children divs increases on hover.

How can i make the parents height be relevant to it's children but also don't increase when their height increases?

As you can see in the code "parent2" has the desired functionality but it's height is fixed which i can't use.

PS without using javascript

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent,
.parent2{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.parent2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

.child:hover {
  height: 150px;
}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zuswrt23/

Comment: if you know how much you increase height, virtually reduce it with a negative margin, else CSS cannot handle this,  use javascript instead.https://jsfiddle.net/2scryzkd/1/ (css, not js)

Answer (score 0):

Is the height of the parent fixed? can you add a max-height to the parent or the child divs?
I did something similar as part of the [100 days CSS challenge.](https://100dayscss.com/) Here's the link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/sagar2510/pen/vvKGNx?editors=1100)

Each child div has a width height.

```
  &:hover {
  font-size: 25px; 
  padding: 70px;
  transition: 0.8s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

On Hover, I'm essentially increasing the width (or in your case, it would be the height) by adding padding rather than increasing the height.

The parent container has a width of 400px and is set to display flex (to accommodate variable child divs)

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
width: 400px;
```